# Передача строки с клиента на сервер, разбиение на меньшие строки и запись в массив. Java

Tags: java, сокет, split

Возникла проблема. Есть работающее клиент-серверное приложение, честно спионеренное с инета, передает строку на сервер через Java Socket. Попытался допилить к серверной части разбиение этой(входящей) строки на подстроки и запись в массив таким образом:

```
String[] sensorBuffer = line.split(" ",6);
```

Вышло не очень, при выводе массива на консоль получается набор символов рандомных.
Далее приведен сам код:

```
 ServerSocket servsocket = new ServerSocket(port); // создание сокета
    System.out.println("Ожидание клиента");

    Socket socket = servsocket.accept(); // Ожидание коннекта
    System.out.println("Клиент подключен");
    System.out.println();

    InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
    OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();

    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);
    String line = null; 
    int counter =0;
    while(true) {
       line = in.readUTF(); // ожидание строки от клиента
        System.out.println("Клиент: " + line);
        String[] sensorBuffer = line.split(" ",6);
        System.out.println(sensorBuffer);
        out.writeUTF(line); // отсылаем клиенту обратно его же строку текста
        out.flush();
        System.out.println("Ожидание следующей строки");
        System.out.println();
        counter++;
        if(counter == 2) { // условие выхода из цикла
            break;
        }
    }
```

И клиента код:

```
public class ClientTest {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int serverPort = 7000; 
    String address = "127.0.0.1"; 


    try {
        InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(address); 
        System.out.println(" IP address " + address + " and port " + serverPort);
        Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress, serverPort); 
        System.out.println("Socket ready");


        InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();


        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);


        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line = null;
        System.out.println("Введите данные и нажмите 'Ввод'");
        System.out.println();

        while (true) {
            line = reader.readLine(); 
            System.out.println("Отправка на сервер");
            out.writeUTF(line); // отправка текста
            out.flush(); // конец передачи
            line = in.readUTF(); // возврат текста от сервера
            System.out.println("Сервер: : " + line);
            System.out.println("Введите новую строку");
            System.out.println();
        }
    } catch (Exception x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

}

В общем прошу помощи, потому что я вообще запутался.

Comment: замените `System.out.println(sensorBuffer);` на `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sensorBuffer));`

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень выручили.